# Cakephp: how do I know what route was used

Tags: logging, cakephp

So I am a total cakephp newb and one of the first things I expected to see was basic info about each page request logged. More specifically, I need what route was used and as a result, what controller/method is called. Obviously I did not find what I was expecting and about the only kind of meaningful info I can find is from the apache logs. What I expected was to see something similar to the first log entry found for a request in a rails app.

Does cakephp not log this kind of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if Cake supports logging of the whole routing process, but on any page you can see what the controller and action are by printing out $this->params in your controller.

If you're trying to debug a routing error that's redirecting you to an error page you can extend the AppError class to do some logging.

I think the reason there's no logging is that everyone tends to use the default /controller_name/action_name/ scheme, making the controller and action self evident.